# Add a variable into a js url path

Tags: javascript, variables, eleventy

I'm trying to a add a variable into the following:

```
eleventyConfig.addPassthroughCopy({ "random-folder/img": "subfolder/img" });
```

What I've tried:

```
var directory = "random-folder";
eleventyConfig.addPassthroughCopy({ directory + "/img": "subfolder/img" });
```

However this does not work. Help hugely appreciated. 
The path to the left of the `:` is the source and to the right is destination. More information on the structure [here](https://www.11ty.dev/docs/copy/#change-the-output-directory) if needed.

Comment: Hey @Quentin I can appreciate the need to remove duplicate questions, but do bear in mind, a JS novice like me would never have identified a solution to my issue in the answer you've specified. My question also relates to 11ty specifically. Looking at the answer you believe my question duplicates, I can see the similarity, but it's still not obvious. Do remember Stackoverflow is used by people learning and growing, they're not all experts and whilst something might look like a duplicate to you, it isn't when you take into consideration skill level and context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to wrap property name in brackets like here:

```js
var directory = "random-folder";
eleventyConfig.addPassthroughCopy({ [directory + "/img"]: "subfolder/img" });
```

Comment: Works a treat, thank you very much for the prompt response!